# Selecting specific revision while editing on mobile has no effect

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, mobile-web, revisions-list

Clicking "edit" for a specific revision on the mobile theme, gets one the expected revision and an edit screen with a dropdown to select another revision. Good. However, selecting another revision on that edit screen has no effect; while on the regular site the page reloads with a different URL, on mobile nothing happens.

[image]   
[image]

Chrome remote debugging does not show any error. It seems that

```
<select id="revisions-list" name="revisions-list" tabindex="99">
```

...has no handler on mobile, while on the regular sites the page itself defines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {        
        $("#wmd-input").focus();
        $("#title").focus();
        $("#revisions-list").change(function() {
          window.location = '/posts/140020/edit/' + $(this).val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tested on both the stock Android 4.1 browser, Chrome on Android 4.1, and Safari on iOS 4.3.3. Same results when using the mobile theme in a regular desktop browser.

As an aside, clicking "edit" on mobile *always* gets me the edit screen with the revision dropdown, even when clicking "edit" or "improve" below a post. I assume that this is by design. (It's just like when not using inline editing on the regular site, like when one has JavaScript disabled.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will go out in the next build.